# ActiveModel Serializers: has_many with condition at run-time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I use rails (5.0.1) and active_model_serializers (0.10.2). I would like to somehow conditionally serialize the `has_many` associations:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :responses, :inverse_of => :question
end

class Response < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :question, :inverse_of => :responses
end

class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :created_at, :updated_at
  has_many :responses
end

class ResponseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title
end
```

I use jsonapi and querying `http://localhost:3000/api/questions/1` I get this  response:

**Response-1**:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "questions",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "First",
      "created-at": "2017-02-14T09:49:20.148Z",
      "updated-at": "2017-02-14T13:55:37.365Z"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "responses": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "responses"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove `has_many :responses` from `QuestionSerializer` I get this:

**Response-2**:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "questions",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "First",
      "created-at": "2017-02-14T09:49:20.148Z",
      "updated-at": "2017-02-14T13:55:37.365Z"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I **conditionally** get either **Response-1** or **Response-2** at run time? I tried all the recommendations found - neither works with AMS 0.10.2. Currently, the condition works only this way:

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :created_at, :updated_at
  has_many :responses if true
end
```

OR:

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :created_at, :updated_at
  has_many :responses if false
end
```

In these 2 cases I really get either **Response-1** or **Response-2**. But   this is hard-coded and I would like to maybe pass a param into the serializer or do some similar thing.

What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

I think you've kind of answered your own question. If you look into the AMS [documentation for associations](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.4/docs/general/serializers.md#associations) it says that conditionals are supported.

From what I can tell you're just a typo away

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   has_many :responses, if: false
end
```

The `attributes` method also supports the `if` option, as described [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.4/docs/general/serializers.md#attributes).

What's your `active_model_serializers` version?

**EDIT**:
I have an error in my answer too. I'm using `active_model_serializers (0.10.3)` and I'm able to do

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   has_many :responses, if: -> { false }
end
```

The `if` option works with either methods, procs or strings. I think you can decide at runtime by providing a method as the conditional.

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attr_writer :should_render_association
  has_many :responses, if: -> { should_render_association }
end
# Usage: 
serializer = QuestionSerializer.new(question)
serializer.should_render_association = false
serializer.to_json
# => no "responses" key
```

Comment: I saw it in the documentation. I use AMS 0.10.2. Be surprised - `if:` condition **doesn't work** (!), only `if` does. Even despite the documentation! The server says: `syntax error, unexpected ':'`. But my question was not about it.

Comment: I updated the answer, I think it works. Sorry if I'm missing something, I thought the whole point was to conditionally render an attribute, but decide at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @gkats, I found an answer (AMS 0.10.2):

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :created_at, :updated_at
  has_many :responses, if: -> { should_render_association }

  def should_render_association
    @instance_options[:show_children]
  end
end

class Api::ResponsesController < Api::ApplicationController
  def show
    render json: @response, show_children: param[:include_children]
  end
end
```

The problem was all about the syntax: `if:` in the serializer should be applied to a block rather than to a function.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with the same issue. Here is working solution I figured.

Initialise with `except: [:key_one, :key_two]` as arguments.

```rb
class QuestionsController
    def index
        @questions = Question.all
        render(json: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@questions,
                                                      each_serializer: QuestionSerializer,
                                                      root: 'questions',
                                                      except: [:responses])
        )
    end

    def show 
        # you can also pass the :except arguments here
        # render(json: QuestionSerializer.new(@question, except: [:responses]).to_json)
        render(json: QuestionSerializer.new(@question).to_json)
    end
end
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/active_model_serializers/0.9.3/ActiveModel%2FArraySerializer:initialize

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/active_model_serializers/0.9.1/ActiveModel%2FSerializer:initialize

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can pass parameters from the parent serializer and show or hide attributes based on these parameters in the child serializer.

**Parent serializer:**

```
class LocationSharesSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :locations, :show_title, :show_address
     
  def locations
    ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(object.locations, {
      each_serializer: PublicLocationSerializer,
      params: { 
        show_title: object.show_title
      },
    })
  end

end
```

**Child serializer**

```
class PublicLocationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :latitude, :longitude, :title, :directions, :description, :address, :tags, :created_at, :updated_at, :photos

  def title
    object.title if @instance_options[:params][:show_title]
  end

end
```