# ActiveModel::Serializers JSON API nested associations include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, json-api

I haven't found the exactly same question on Stackoverflow. Besides AMS changes so rapidly, that even 2-year-old answers get outdated often.

I use Rails 5 API-only and the gem 'active_model_serializers' (AMS) (ver. 0.10.6).

I also use the JSONAPI response format - not simply JSON.

I need to render a **nested include** - not just nested relations as of now.

Code example:

serializer1:

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :created_at, :updated_at
  belongs_to :user
end
```

serializer2:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email
  has_many :cities
end
```

serializer3:

```
class CitySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

controller:

```
def index
  @questions = Question.all
  render json: @questions, include: [:user, 'user.city']
end
```

I get this response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "questions",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "First",
        "created-at": "2017-03-27T13:22:15.548Z",
        "updated-at": "2017-03-27T13:22:16.463Z"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "user": {
          "data": {
            "id": "3",
            "type": "users"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "included": [
    {
      "id": "3",
      "type": "users",
      "attributes": {
        "email": "client2@example.com"   
      },
      "relationships": {
        "cities": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "75",
              "type": "cities"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I really do get a nested relation `city`. I even get the city `id`.

But the problem is - how do I get other `city` attributes like `name`? I need another `include` section - maybe inside current `include` section (nested?).

How to do that? (without any additional gems)

Answer (score 1):

I found some solution. I don't know about how clean is it. It is based on 2 prerequisites:

1. https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/db6083af2fb9932f9e8591e1d964f1787aacdb37/docs/general/adapters.md#included
2. [ActiveModel Serializers: has_many with condition at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244237/activemodel-serializers-has-many-with-condition-at-run-time/42339208#42339208)

I applied the conditional relations and `user`-all-permissive `include`:

controller:

```
@questions = Question.all

render json: @questions,

show_user: (param? params[:user]),

show_cities: (param? params[:city]),

include: [:user, "user.**"]
```

serializer1:

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :created_at, :updated_at
  belongs_to :user, if: -> { should_render_user }

  def should_render_user
    @instance_options[:show_user]
  end   
end
```

serializer2:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email
  has_many :cities, if: -> { should_render_cities }

  def should_render_cities
    @instance_options[:show_cities]
  end    
end
```

serializer3:

```
class CitySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

helper:

```
def param? param

  param && param != "false" && param != "nil"

end
```

Conditional relations allow to control which `include`'s actually to render.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it

```
render json: @questions, include: [:categories, user: :city]
```

Comment: No, it did not. The result is the same.

Comment: You must have set the attributes from somewhere for city model

Comment: usually you will get all attributes unless you are allowing some specific attributes

Comment: I don't understand you.

Answer (score 0):

You should also include the user in the parameter 'fields' and using strings instead of symbols for the parameter include

```
render json: @questions, fields: [:title, :user], include: ['user', 'user.cities']
```